# If there is an xpath expression saved in a node, is there a way to execute that statement?

Tags: javascript, xpath

In the XML document below, I am trying to figure out how to get the result of the xpath statement that is saved in node B.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Example>
    <A>test1</A>
    <B>A/text()</B>
</Example>
```

The text value of node A is test1.
The text value of node B is A/text().

I would like to execute the XPath statement from node B which will provide the value of node A.

I have tested (B/text())/text() but that did not return anything.
I tried change the value of node B to A and then used statement (B/text())/text(), but that did not return anything either.

Comment: Get the text of the node into a variable. Then pass that variable as the argument to the function that does an XPath lookup.

Comment: If you evaluate `A/text()` (i.e. the string value of the `B` element) in the context of the `Example` element, it should give you the result you want. But simply show us your JavaScript code, here on Stackoverflow you can easily embed an executable code snippet of JavaScript demonstrating your failing attempt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the browser side (DOM Level 3 XPath) `evaluate` method:

```js
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Example>
    <A>test1</A>
    <B>A/text()</B>
</Example>`;

const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');

const result = xmlDoc.evaluate(xmlDoc.evaluate('Example/B', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE).stringValue, xmlDoc.documentElement, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE).stringValue;

console.log(result);
```